# glfwOpenWindow fail on osx yosemite

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, compilation

I am trying to build and run the following project on OS X Yosemite to play with ray marching & shaders:

https://github.com/lightbits/ray-march/blob/master/raymarch-dev.md

I am not too familiar with compilation on OS X nor openGL.

**The error:**

I got the project to compile but « glfwOpenWindow » fail on,

```
glfwOpenWindow(
width, height,
8, 8, 8, 0,
24, 8,
false )
```

I don’t get any error message and don’t know why it failed. I think the problem comes from what I did to build the codebase.

**What I did:**

The external includes are:

```
#include <glload/gl_3_1_comp.h> // OpenGL version 3.1, compatability profile
#include <glload/gll.hpp>   // The C-style loading interface
#include <GL/glfw.h>    // Context
#include <glm/glm.hpp>  // OpenGL mathematics
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp> // for value_ptr(matrix)
#include <string>
```

- I installed homebrew
- I installed cmake
- I built GLFW-legacy
- I installed glm.
- I replaced, in "opengl.h",

  `#include <glload/gl_3_1_comp.h> // OpenGL version 3.1, compatability profile
   #include <glload/gll.hpp>  // The C-style loading interface`

with,

```
`#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>`
```

- I removed, in  "opengl.cpp".

  `if(glload::LoadFunctions() == glload::LS_LOAD_FAILED)
      return false;`
- my current compiling command is:

  `g++ main.cpp fileio.cpp opengl.cpp -I /usr/local/include/GL/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -framework OpenGL -lGLFW`

Comment: There were no compilation errors?

Comment: No only a warning:  gl.h and gl3.h are both included. Compiler will not invoke errors if
      using removed OpenGL functionality

Answer (score 0):

From the linked code, we have [opengl.cpp](https://github.com/lightbits/ray-march/blob/master/src/opengl.cpp) with

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,         0); // 0 lets the system choose the profile
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR,   OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR,   OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES,           fsaa);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE,       GL_TRUE);
```

together with the [header file](https://github.com/lightbits/ray-march/blob/master/src/opengl.h):

```
const int OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR = 3;
const int OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR = 1;
```

So this is requesting an OpenGL 3.1 context _which is never supported on OSX?. OSX onlz supports legacz contexts up to GL 2.1, or GL core profile contexts beginning with GL 3.2. GLFW will of course fail to create the GL context.

I haven't checked the rest of the code, but you might get away with explicitely requestiong a GL 3.2 core profile.

Comment: THat is probaly not enough, you will also have to adjust the `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE` hint, and might as well also have to add the gorward compat hint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, to request a core profile, I set OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR to 2 and changed <GL/glfw.h> to <GLFW/glfw3.h>. But I then get many errors at compile time. Does that mean that the code is not compatible with osx?
Edit: Following @derhass advice, I added,  glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,  GL_TRUE); and set GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE to 1. It still crash on glfwOpenWindow with <GL/glfw.h>